# Should simple enums derive Copy? Is there any difference in performance?

Tags: rust

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

// #[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum SomeEnum {
    Some1,
    Some2,
}

struct SomeStruct {
    pub some_enum: SomeEnum,
    pub s: String,
}

fn proc_struct(some_struct: &SomeStruct) {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(String::from("any"), 0);

    match map.get(&some_struct.s) { // just to make a reference in SomeStruct
        Some(v) => {
            proc1(some_struct.some_enum);
            proc2(&some_struct.some_enum);
        }
        None => {}
    }
}

fn proc1(some: SomeEnum) {}

fn proc2(some: &SomeEnum) {}

fn main() {
    let some_struct = SomeStruct { some_enum: SomeEnum::Some1, s: String::from("s") };

    proc_struct(&some_struct);
}
```

The above code produces the following error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:20:19
   |
20 |             proc1(some_struct.some_enum);
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

When I add `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` to `SomeEnum`, it compiles fine.

Should simple enums like `SomeEnum` derive the `Copy` trait?
Is there any difference in performance between functions `proc1()` and `proc2()`?

Comment: For reference, this was [cross-posted to the Rust user's forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/should-simple-enum-derive-copy-trait/11483?u=shepmaster).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Citing the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#when-should-my-type-be-copy):

> Generally speaking, if your type can implement `Copy`, it should.

Since your `SomeEnum` has no composite variants (e.g. `Vec`s or `String`s), I recommend making it `Copy`able. It appears that it is actually smaller than a reference to it:

```
use std::mem;

enum SomeEnum {
    Some1,
    Some2,
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(1, mem::size_of::<SomeEnum>());
    assert_eq!(8, mem::size_of::<&SomeEnum>());
}
```

Though I doubt that in this case you will be able to detect any difference in performance.